React leaflet. map is not showing
I have been trying to create a map section in my website for at least an hour now, but the react-leaflet or leaflet just won't work at all. I do every step that the doc says, I have watched a lot of videos, checked the other questions on the website and tried them, and I'm pretty sure that I do everything correct but it is the same for me. My computer has no problem, all necessary libs are installed in case you may ask (I'm using vite).
i was expecting this result:

Please, don't hesitate to tell me what may cause this irritating problem if you know.
this is the component.
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

const position = [40, 0];

export default function ContactLocation() {
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="container max-w-full h-[600px]">
        <MapContainer
          center={position}
          zoom={15}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
          className="h-[80vh]"
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={position}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

this is the result:

the problem is with the vite. i have wrote the same code using create-react app, it worked. so the main problem right now is what to do for vite and i have no idea.
this is the vite.config.js file


import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import * as path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
})




In your browser's network tab, you should see the list of tiles requested from OpenstreetMap, if you click on one, what do you see (request url, params, etc.) ?

is it possible that vite may cause this problem? because i've tried every single way but still the same. i have tried the previous versions of leaflet but no luck.

I don't know, maybe try comparing your code with some of the examples here : https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/react-leaflet

Sir, i have also checked them, and i just discovered source of the issue. the problem is probably due to vite as i thought. So, I created a new project using create-react-app and wrote the same code in there, it worked. now i have no idea what to do about vite configuration, but im guessing you may know something to solve

I don't know, do you have errors in your browser's console ?

not a single error, sir

i have been working on the huge project and got stuck on this part unfortunately.

do you see the map (in vite project) when you resize the browser? if so, you might need to add a invalidateSize trigger.
